# Facebook Like Refreshes my pages

Tags: jquery, facebook, button, facebook-like

i am using the wordpress buddypress community plugin, 
and i put wp-facebook connect & i wanted to add a simple
Facebook LIke button into posts, 
when i put an XFBML of the like buttons, its going into a loop of refreshing.
i think it is two XFBML colliding... (the connect button and the like 2 diffrent wightds.) 
is there a code i can ADD to stop my page from reloading? 
http://meshpuha.com
Thank you for your time, regareds! :)